# Mobile browser time inputs don't work inside vue element

Tags: ios, html, vuejs2

I have a laravel webapp that uses multiple forms. I have recently introduced Vue.js v2 to deal with some specific custom input types which are working well.

Problem is that ordinary html5 input[type=time] inputs that are inside the vue instance element are not rendered properly in iOS safari/chrome - they appear as native timepickers but appear to have a blank value. When you click to change they do display the correct value.

I can workaround by using a custom vue component that just passes the value property into the vue instance but I figure I must be doing something wrong because I can't find a single mention of this anywhere.

[I have managed to reproduce this on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ay5x07q/5/) **problem only appears in mobile browsers**

**html**

```
<div id="app" style="background-color:lightblue; padding:30px">
  <h3>This div is the Vue element</h3>
  <form action="">
    <p>  
      <label for="">Standard Input</label>
      <input type="time" value="23:24:00" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">Vue Component</label>
      <vue-time value="13:45:00"></vue-time>
    </p>

  </form>
</div>

<div style="background-color:lightyellow; padding:30px">
  <h3>This div is outside the Vue instance</h3>
  <form action="">
    <label for="">Standard Input</label>
    <input type="time" value="23:24:00" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**js**

```
Vue.component('vue-time', {
    template: '<input type="time" :value="value">',
    data() {
        return {
                value: ''
        }
    }
});

const vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            value: ''
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem and I found this thread that helped me, see if it helps you:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-fixed-position-element-disappears-during-transition-on-mobile-browsers/8960

I would comment on your question instead of proposing this as an answer but I don't have the reputation to do so yet.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it [hasn't made any difference](https://jsfiddle.net/9ay5x07q/6/)